# Magento 2 : override Magento_Sales::email/items/creditmemo/default.phtml

Tags: magento2, module, template, overrides

What is the best way to override below template file in module ?

```
Magento_Sales::email/items/creditmemo/default.phtml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create below XML file in your custom module here..

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_creditmemo_renderers.xml

Content for this file..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.creditmemo.renderers.default">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::order/creditmemo/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.print.creditmemo.renderers.grouped">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::order/creditmemo/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And you can add your phtml file here..

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/order/creditmemo/items/renderer/default.phtml

After changing this, flush Magento cache once.

That's it. Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
let me check

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working.